# Create mySQL TableAdapter in VS2017

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

for a service in my company i need to create a DataSet with two TableAdapters.

The source of the first TableAdapter is MSSQL.

The source of the second one is mySQL.
When i try to create the second one i get the following error.
[image]

Did someone encounter this problem befor?

I'm using VS2017. I also installed MySQL for VS (Version 1.2.7), Connector/ODBC (Version 5.3.9) and Connector/NET (Version 6.10.5).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the C# code? So we can understand what you are doing

Comment: It seems there is a missing `object obj_name = new obj_type()`

Comment: @RaymondNijland there is no c# code. Its an item of type DataSet where I try to add the TableAdapter with the wizard

Comment: Wierd why is this tagged C# then? Unless you are trying to connect to MSSQL and MySQL from visual studio 2017 then this question is offtopic for Stackoverflow

Comment: I do. The connection to the MSSQL works fine, but when trying to create the MySQL TableAdapter the error above shows up

Comment: You should ask this question on https://superuser.com there they handle software and hardware related questions on Stackoverflow it's only programming related questions. That's why i voted closed this question.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your time!